# Unable to locate the model you have specified: Login_model

Tags: codeigniter

I have created login_model.php file my models folder.But When I am executing the function,It gives the error.But it Works fine on local server but after uploading only it gives error.

Please help me out.Thanks In Advance.

Comment: where is the code

Comment: which version are you using

Comment: 3.1.8 version@Re

Comment: $data = array(
'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
'password' => $this->input->post('password')
);
$this->load->model('login_model');
$result=$this->login_model->login($data);

if ($result == FALSE) {
 $data = array(
'error_message' => 'Invalid Username or Password'
);

 $this->load->view('login_view',$data);
}

Comment: are your model file name is as same as with the model class? can you share your code first sir?

Comment: @rohit there is a edit button below your question click on that and you can re edit your question and put code rather than in comments.

Answer (score 0):

The filename is case-sensitive, should be `Login_model.php`, and should declare `class Login_model extends CI_Model` again note the capitalization.

Then assuming this file is not in a sub-folder in `application/models` the model can be loaded via `$this->load->model('login_model');`